# Restarting an executable based on terminal output

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, gnome-terminal

**Backstory:** I'm working with a piece of software that uses CMake for several build options. On my desktop build system when I execute a 'Processor Reset' command the program exits cleanly, but needs restarted with a different set of parameters. (The functionality works correctly on hardware, so I do not wish to modify the underlying source whatsoever.)

**Question:** My question is, how can I monitor the terminal output from the program, and upon seeing "Processor Reset Received", trigger a new instance of the program?

#### Caveats

- My preferred answer would perform this in a shell script, but I'm open to other ideas.
- I do not wish for there to be any recursion.

#### General Flow

- Start the program with a Power-On Reset

  ```
  ./program -PO
  ```

  (Program runs and prints output to terminal)
- Send a Processor Reset Command
- Program receives Processor Reset Command, prints relevant information, and terminates
- Monitor program reads that the original program has terminates with a Processor Reset, and runs the program again with different flags.

  ```
  ./program -PR
  ```

#### Things I've tried

I have a partially working solution that... is interesting. It appears that there is some weird buffering going on which I've tried to disable, albeit unsuccessfully. But - it does successfully parse the program's terminal output and execute the Processor Reset flags when necessary (albeit once, as it is not in a loop.)

```
stdbuf -o0 -i0 -e0 sudo ./program -PO | tee /dev/tty | (grep "Processor Reset.") | (read && sudo ./program -PR)
```

#### To recap

- I need the code to not buffer large chunks of data (i.e. write smoothly as it produces output)
- It should be wrapped in a loop to allow multiple Processor Resets. (Any other reset should terminate the loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to slm for pointing me in the right direction!

```
# Start the program with Power-On Reset
# Use tee to print output to terminal and pipe to grep
# grep returns 0 if the string is found
sudo ./program -PO | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "Processor Reset."

# Store the grep exit code in a variable
result="$?"

# If result is 0, grep found the Processor Reset string
if [ "$result" == "0" ]; then
  while : ; do
  sudo ./program -PR | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "Processor Reset."
  result="$?"

# This loop will continue as long as the Processor Reset string is found
# once the program terminates
  [ "$result" == "0" ] || break
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you have a shell script like so:

```
$ cat top.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "launched top.bash"
./fakeprog1.bash | grep -q "Processor Reset Received" && exec ./fakeprog2.bash
```

You can replace the `./fakeprog1.bash` with your `./program -PO` and `./fakeprog2.bash` with your `./program -PR`.

When I invoke my version it runs like so:

```
$ ./top.bash
launched top.bash
launching /root/453742/fakeprog2.bash
```

The `fakeprog1.bash` echos a message but we cannot see it because it gets filtered out by the `grep`. Logs can be directed to files + this script via `tee` so that shouldn't be a issue.

Comment: I think this is close, however it doesn't allow for multiple Processor Resets?

Comment: @Ramrod - can you explain what you want to happen overall with that? Your example only shows 1 iteration like that.

Comment: My answer below is probably the best way to show what I'm after. But, after looking at it (and the more I learn) I don't think I'm really using tee correctly. That code functions, but buffers very slowly to the terminal screen.